# Im having a problem with mysql syntax while setting a new user for a rails application in my database. How do i solve it

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

this what i did in mysql command line

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE demo_project_development;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE demo_project_test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_project_development.* TO 'rails_user'@'localhost' 
       IDENTIFIED BY 'secretpassword';
```

> **ERROR 1064** (**42000**): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'secretpassword'' at line 1

Comment: try to remove quotes within `'rails_user'@'localhost'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
GRANT ALL ON my_project_development TO rails_user
```

check [this site](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-grant.aspx) as well..